# application has been blocked from accessing graphics

Tags: opencv, image-processing, webcam, video-capture

Hi I am trying to write a program that use my laptop webcam. After the program starts and camera view is displayed, camera view is freeze and stop working. My computer give me that error notification "application has been blocked from accessing graphics". I am using AMD Radeon graphics, Win 8.1, VS2013 and OpenCV 3.0.

I seacrhed on the internet but there was problems about games. I cant find any reletad issue for developers.

How can I fix it?

Comment: how can anyone answer when you did not provide any useful data like: Which Language/Compiler (x86/x64), OS (you wrote win 8.1 but x86/x64 ?), Drivers(gfx,webcam), what API and techniques you use for image acquisition (DX,VFW?) and rendering (GDI,GL,DX?, 2D,3D,...). What about small source code that show us this behavior (MCE). My bet is that you have some memory leak in your program AMD/ATI drivers are extremly sensitive to such things. Another reason but high unlikely is that you have small bandwidth on USB for your webcam to work(last seen this in USB 1.1 days but behaves the same)

Comment: Have you tried different computer (different gfx card) ?